# Removing './' untracked file in git

Tags: git, macos

While playing around with a git command, I run the following command:

```
git checkout-index --prefix=./test
```

thinking it would checkout files into the `test` directory. (After running it, it is clear that it doesn't.) However, I know have the following when I run `git status`:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ./

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How do I get rid of this file? It doesn't appear when I do `ls -la` (other than the normal `.` and `..` displayed).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `checkout-index` command is responsible for your current situation.  First, it behaves pretty much exactly like you assumed. Let's say we start with a clone of the [hello-world](https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world) repository, and run:

```
$ git checkout-index --prefix=./test README.md
```

This will checkout the file `README.md`, prefixing it with `./test`, so we get a file named `testREADME.md`:

```
$ ls *README*
README.md  testREADME.md
```

If we wanted that in a subdirectory, we would need to remember the trailing `/`:

```
$ git checkout-index --prefix=./test/ README.md
$ ls test
README.md
```

Neither of these operations disrupts the repository state.  Running `git status` at this point yields:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test/
    testREADME.md
```

...which is pretty much what we would expect.  I suspect that you ran some additional commands in addition to `checkout-index` that have resulted in the current situation.

Comment: Ah, this is rather embarrassing. It looks like I have that output because I run git status in a newly created directory that wasn't yet checked in. I have wrongly associated this with running git checkout-index.